# Identifier 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to make a signup page with a validator for password confirmation.
The problem is that I am getting an error Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member.
I am fairly new to programming is clueless to why this is happening

I tried googling for solutions but no luck

validator.ts code

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function passwordMatchValidator(pwSet: FormGroup) {
var password = pwSet.controls.password.value;
var password2 = pwSet.controls.password2.value;
if (!(password === password2)) return {'notmatch': true} ;
return null;
}
```

component.ts code

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group ({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['',    [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    role: ['', Validators.required],
    pwSet : this.fb.group ({
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      password2: ['', [Validators.required]]
      }, {validator: passwordMatchValidator})
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.regUser(this.myForm.value.username, this.myForm.value.email, this.myForm.value.role, this.myForm.get('pwSet.password').value).subscribe(data => {
    this.results1 = data;
    if (this.results1[0].auth1){
      this.exist = true;
    }else{
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }
    });
  }
}
```

component.html error:

[image: component.html error]

```
<mat-form-field formGroupName="pwSet" appearance="fill" class="example-full-width2">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="password" id="password" matInput type="password" >
      <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.pwSet.controls.password.dirty && 
        myForm.controls.pwSet.controls.password.hasError('minlength')">
        Password must have a minimum of 8 characters
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls.pwSet.controls.password.dirty && 
        myForm.controls.pwSet.controls.password.hasError('required')">
        Password is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: try changing `myForm.controls.pwSet.controls...` to `myForm.get('pwSet').controls...` (do this same method for any of the errors)

Comment: or `myForm.get('pwSet.password').controls...` / `myForm.get('pwSet.password').hasError....`